# How to close the menu by following the links or clicking outside using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My goal here is to close the menu when I click outside of it or if I click on the links. I would like to achieve it using pure Javascript. Right now my menu opens when I click on the icon and I can close it when I click outside my nav (what is great) but my menu icon isn't working anymore because it's inside my nav element. I've tried some different scenarios with `Element.closest()` and `event.target` (trying to replicate a jquery solution) and `window.addEventListener` but without success. Could someone check my code, please?

```js
const menuIcon = document.querySelector(".hamburger-menu");
        const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");

        menuIcon.addEventListener("click", () =>{
            navbar.classList.toggle("change")
        })

       window.addEventListener('click', function(e){ 
              
            if (document.querySelector('.navbar').contains(e.target)){
                navbar.classList.add("change")

            } else{
                navbar.classList.remove("change")
            }
       });
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #b6b6b6;
}

.hamburger-menu{
        width: 35px;
        height: 30px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 35px;
        right:15px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .line{
        height: 3px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        transition: all .8s;
    }


    .change .line-1{
        transform: rotateZ(-405deg) translate(-8px, 6px);
    }

    .change .line-2{
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .change .line-3{
        transform: rotateZ(405deg) translate(-8px, -6px);
    }

    .navbar{
        width: 210px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color:rgb(0, 128, 255) ;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: -300px;
        z-index: 1000;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        transition: right .8s cubic-bezier(.32,2,.55,.27);

    }

    
    .change{
        right: 0;
    }

    .nav-list{
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;

    }

    .nav-item{
        margin: 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
    
        
    }

    .nav-link{
       font-family: 'Muli-Light', sans-serif;
       letter-spacing: 1.2px;
       text-transform: uppercase;
       text-decoration: none;
       color: white;
    }
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <div class="hamburger-menu">
                    <div class="line line-1"></div>
                    <div class="line line-2"></div>
                    <div class="line line-3"></div>
                </div>

                <ul class="nav-list">
                   <li class='nav-item'>
                      <a href="#" class='nav-link'>Item 1</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class='nav-item'>
                      <a href="#" class='nav-link'>Item 2</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class='nav-item'>
                      <a href="#" class='nav-link'>Item 3</a>
                   </li>
                </ul>

            </nav>
        </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Add a tabIndex to your element. So that the element can have a `focus` state.

```
<nav id="yourMenu" tabIndex="0">
    // Content
</nav>
```

Step 2: Create an event listener, which fires an event when the menu is no longer focused.

```
document.getElementById('yourMenu').addEventListener('blur', () => {
    // Call close function
    closeMenu();
});
```

Step 3: Bind the `closeMenu()` function to your menu items.

Step 4: Make sure you focus the menu before opening. For this simply use
`document.getElementById('yourMenu').focus();`

```js
let menu = null;
let button = null;

(function () {
    menu = document.getElementById('nav');
    button = document.getElementById('openButton');

    menu.addEventListener('blur', () => {
        menu.classList.add('hide');
    });

    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (!menu.classList.contains('hide')) return;
        menu.classList.remove('hide');
        menu.focus();
    });
})();
```

```css
.side-bar {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 300px;
        height: 100vh;
        background: red;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: left 1s linear;
        color: #fff;
}

.side-bar.hide {
    left: -300px;
}

.open-button {
    position: absolute;
    height: 56px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: green;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav id="nav" tabIndex="0" class="side-bar hide">
    CLICK OUTSIDE THE MENU<br> TO CLOSE IT
    </nav>
    <button id="openButton" class="open-button">Open menu</button>
</body>
```